# Количество рабочих дней в месяце запросом mysql

Tags: mysql, запрос

Имеется табличка вида (условно)

```
  id| type|                 date |
|---|-----|----------------------|
| 1 |   2 | 2018-08-01 14:11:00  |
| 1 |   1 | 2018-08-01 14:11:00  |
| 2 |   2 | 2018-08-01 14:11:00  |
```

`id` это айдишник юзера, `type` это включил или выключил компьютер.
Нужно посчитать сколько дней в месяце каждый сотрудник был на рабочем месте.

Сделал вот такой запрос

```
SELECT p.id,CONCAT(p.sname,' ', p.fname ,' ',p.patronymic)  as ФИО, count(day(l.date)) as Дата FROM `t_log` as l, `t_users` as u, t_people as p
WHERE l.user_id = u.id 
AND u.people_id = p.id
AND month(l.date) = 8 and year(l.date) = 2018
GROUP BY ФИО,day(l.date)
```

И получил

```
  Фио         | Кол-во записей для каждого дня| 
|-------------|-------------------------------|
| Вася Пупкин |   10                          | 
| Вася Пупкин |   5                           | 
| Иван Иванов |   8                           |
```

Подскажите, как сделать в виде

```
пользователь | кол-во дней с записями
-------------|-----------------------|
Вася пупкин  |                     2 |
Иван Иванов  |                     1 |
```

Comment: `count(distinct date(l.date))`

Comment: Слово distinct добавьте как я показал выше - оно даст как раз количество уникальных дней, что вам видимо и требуется

Comment: именно то, что нужно! спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
count(distinct date(l.date))
```

– Mike 23 авг в 14:25

Вот был дан правильный ответ в комментариях

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(data, "%Y-%m-%e"))
FROM `users`
GROUP BY user_id, DATE_FORMAT(data, "%Y-%m-%e")
```

имя юзера подцепите сами?

Comment: Увы, тот же результат. Считает количество записей для каждого дня и получается запись с айди юзера  - количество записей в дне и так для каждого дня и юзера

Comment: я не просто так написал. в рабочей БД создал таблицу и проверил запрос. 
значит у вас еще что то о чем не сказано

Comment: Возможно я неправильно выразился. В таблице журнала записи типа пользователь - дата+время. За день у одного пользователя таких записей много. Нужно посчитать сколько дней в месяце с этими записями для каждого пользователя.